# RStudio not starting due to special characters (Finnish) after RStudio update July 2022

Tags: r, rstudio, special-characters, finnish

I have updated RStudio to the 2022.07.1 release. After doing this I have this main error:

```
[5916:15972:20220727,101905.256:ERROR crash_report_database_win.cc:586] CreateDirectory C:/Users/KÃ¤yttÃ¤jÃ¤/AppData/Local/R/crashpad_database: The system cannot find the path specified. (3)
```

Have tried;

- I cannot change the Käyttäjä (user) folder name and have tried to save RStudio in different folders to avoid the path.
- When I type this path into the control panel it finds the folder - so it exists
- This problem has to derive from the update somehow as RStudio was working correctly this morning
- As I cannot even start RStudio I cannot apply any other solution such as Sys.setlocale(locale = "Chinese") as I have seen suggested in others who had problems with special characters in January.

The problem report is here - please say if you need any more information!

---

### R Session Startup Failure Report

#### RStudio Version

RStudio 2022.07.1+554, "Spotted Wakerobin" (7872775e, 2022-07-22) for Windows

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) QtWebEngine/5.12.8 Chrome/69.0.3497.128 Safari/537.36

#### Error message

[No error available]

#### Process Output

The R session exited with code 1.

Error output:

```
[5916:15972:20220727,101905.256:ERROR crash_report_database_win.cc:586] CreateDirectory C:/Users/KÃ¤yttÃ¤jÃ¤/AppData/Local/R/crashpad_database: The system cannot find the path specified. (3)
```

Standard output:

```
[No output emitted]
```

#### Logs

*C:/Users/Käyttäjä/AppData/Local/RStudio/log/rsession-joanna.log*

```
2022-07-27T07:19:05.256764Z [rsession-joanna] ERROR system error 2 (The system cannot find the file specified); OCCURRED AT class rstudio::core::Error __cdecl rstudio::core::crash_handler::initialize(enum rstudio::core::crash_handler::ProgramMode) src/cpp/core/CrashHandler.cpp:322; LOGGED FROM: int __cdecl main(int,char *const []) C:\Users\jenkins\workspace\ide\open-source-pipeline\spotted-wakerobin\src\cpp\session\SessionMain.cpp:2007
2022-07-27T07:19:05.268856Z [rsession-joanna] ERROR system error 2 (The system cannot find the file specified); OCCURRED AT class rstudio::core::Error __cdecl rstudio::core::crash_handler::initialize(enum rstudio::core::crash_handler::ProgramMode) src/cpp/core/CrashHandler.cpp:322; LOGGED FROM: int __cdecl main(int,char *const []) C:\Users\jenkins\workspace\ide\open-source-pipeline\spotted-wakerobin\src\cpp\session\SessionMain.cpp:2057
2022-07-27T07:19:05.268856Z [rsession-joanna] ERROR system error 2 (The system cannot find the file specified); OCCURRED AT class rstudio::core::Error __cdecl rstudio::core::crash_handler::initialize(enum rstudio::core::crash_handler::ProgramMode) src/cpp/core/CrashHandler.cpp:322; LOGGED FROM: int __cdecl main(int,char *const []) C:\Users\jenkins\workspace\ide\open-source-pipeline\spotted-wakerobin\src\cpp\session\SessionMain.cpp:2057
```

### Edit

Submitted to rstudio will reply for more updates.

Comment: Please submit bug reports to the RStudio developers.

Comment: Is it more likely a bug than my configuration being wrong?

Comment: Well, if this occured after an RStudio update it looks like a bug or at least a regression.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is having the same problem and stumbles upon this. I did mange to get RStudio to open by going to the problem folder, right clicking to find properties, and changing the permissions to allow folders to be written there (Windows solution).

So far there seem not to be any side effects...